# A square ABCD has all it's vertices on $x^2y^2 = 1$. Midpoints of it's sides also lie on the same curve . Can I show diagonals of it meet at origin?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

A square ABCD has all it's vertices on $x^2y^2 = 1$. The midpoints of it's sides also lie on the same curve . What is the area of this square ?

It can be found very easily if we can show that diagonal of this square meet at the origin.

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Tangents to the hyperbolas at $(\pm1, \pm1)$!

Comment: "It can be found very easily if ... ." From this, I suppose you already know how to find the area of the square. If that is true, you should show what you have done in the question, at least enough to convince most people not to waste their time showing you how to find a result you have already found. Then you could focus on the step where you assume the center of the square is at the origin, which is not explicitly given in the problem statement.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with

$$A(a,1/a) \ \ \text{with} \ \ a=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}\tag{1}$$

the other points $B,C,D$ being obtained by rotations from $A$ with angles $k\pi/2$.

[image]

*Fig. 1.*

Indeed, as there is one (hyperbolic) branch per quadrant $Q_k$, let us look for a solution where $A \in Q_1$, $B \in Q_2$ and midpoint $E=(A+B)/2 \in Q_1$.

Using complex number representation, let

$$A(x_1,\frac{1}{x_1})\leftrightarrow x_1+i \frac{1}{x_1} \ \ \text{and} \ \  B(x_2,\frac{1}{x_2})\leftrightarrow x_2-i \frac{1}{x_2}.$$

Let us express that $\vec{OB}$ is the image of $\vec{OA}$ by the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ rotation with center $O$:

$$i \left(x_1+i \frac{1}{x_1} \right)=\left(x_2-i \frac{1}{x_2} \right) \ \implies \ x_2=- \frac{1}{x_1} \ \implies \ x_1x_2=-1\tag{2}$$

Midpoint $E$ of $[AB]$ has coordinates.

$$\frac12 \left( x_1+i \frac{1}{x_1} + x_2-i \frac{1}{x_2}\right)= \underbrace{\frac12(x_1+x_2)}_x+i  \underbrace{\frac12\left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_1x_2}\right)}_y $$

Now let us take into account the fact that we want the midpoint $E$ of $[AB]$ to belong to the branch in $Q_1$ by expressing that $xy=1$:

$$x_2^2-x_1^2=4x_1x_2\tag{3}$$

From (2) and (3), one gets :

$$\dfrac{1}{x_1^2}-x_1^2=-4\tag{4}$$

Setting $X=x_1^2$, on gets the quadratic equation:

$$X^2-4X-1=0\tag{5}$$

whose unique positive root is $X=2+\sqrt{5}$ giving $x_1=\sqrt{X}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}$ as said in (1).

easily obtain (1) by solving a quadratic.

[image]

*Fig. 2: Explanation for the global solution: We have been working (red color) on the first branch of hyperbola $xy=1$ + right isosceles triangle. This basic pattern" is then rotated 3 times giving the green, blue, and black parts. The desired square is generated by the union of the 4 right isosceles triangles.*

**Consequence for the area of the square:**

This area is given by the square $L^2$ of the following distance

$$L=dist(A,B)=dist(a,\dfrac{1}{a}),(-\dfrac{1}{a},a))$$

As a consequence:

$$L^2=(a+\dfrac{1}{a})^2+(a-\dfrac{1}{a})^2$$

$$L^2=2(a^2+\dfrac{1}{a^2})=2+\sqrt{5}-(2-\sqrt{5})=4 \sqrt{5}$$

Remark 1: By using reflections with respect to axes Ox and Oy, three other solutions can be obtained.

Reamrk 2: Maybe, by a suitable similitude (rotation + enlargment or shrinking)

$$\begin{cases}x'&=&(r \cos \theta) x  - (r \sin \theta) y\\y'&=&(r \sin \theta) x  + (r \cos \theta) y
\end{cases},$$

the problem can be settled with a *fixed* square with vertices $(1,1),(-1,1),(-1,-1),(1,-1)$ and a certain fourth degree polynomial under one of its canonical forms as for example given in [Some new canonical forms for polynomials by B. REZNICK](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.310.7968&rep=rep1&type=pdf) amenable to the form $x^2y^2=1$ by the reversed change of variable...

Comment: Because in a rotation by angle $\alpha$, if $A',B'$ are the images of $A,B$ resp. then angle $(\vec{AB},\vec{A'B'})$ is $\alpha$ as well.

Comment: If you mentally group the branch of hyperbola in the first quadrant ($x>0, y>0$ and the line AEB, rotation with center 0 and angle $\pi/2$ will exactly fit into the place of the second branch of the hyperbola (in the second quadrant) and line $BC$...

Comment: A remark: I have had a look at your past questions: you seldom upvote/validate answers. Please at least upvote the answers who have brought you something. It is important for people who have spend time on it ; it is also important for other readers who know in this way the answer to be read first. Consider validation for the best answer if you do not intend to come back to this question.

Comment: See Fig. 2 and its legend.

Comment: Do you agree that the first branch (in the first quadrant) has equation $y=1/x$ and that the second branch (in the second quadrant) has equation $y=-1/x$ ? Therefore if I have a first point $A_1=(x_1+i\dfrac{1}{x_1})$ in the first branch such that that when multiplied by $i=e^{i \pi/2}$ gives a point $A_2=(x_2+i\dfrac{-1}{x_2})$ (with minus sign in front of 1 !) we are in the desired situation : $\vec{OA_2}$ is the image of $\vec{OA_1}$ by a $\pi/2$ rotation. This is what is done...

Comment: I think you are not pursuing the right problem. Just consider the four vertices found in this way and check that their midpoints belong to the double hyperbola.

Comment: I have read anew your title (has it always been the same ?). I understand now your point : you want to be certain that no other solution exists with a center which is not the origin.

Comment: It is not the answer of the question.

Comment: @INDIAN consider that  I have made significative contributions to this question, in particular that I have exhibited a solution (which wasn't evident), I have answered to the question "What is the area of this square ?", I have taken time to give to graphical representations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If $(x_0,y_0)$ is the centre of the square and the vector $(2u,2v)$ corresponds to one of the edges (wlog. $u\ge v\ge 0$), then all the points
$$ (x_0+\alpha u+\beta v,y_0+\alpha v-\beta v)$$
with $\alpha,\beta\in\{-1,0,1\}$, except $\alpha=\beta=0$, are on the curve. That is,
$$\tag1 (x_0+\alpha u+\beta v)(y_0+\alpha v-\beta u)=\pm1.$$
The only quadratic polynomials $Ax^2+Bx+C$ that take values $\pm1$ for all $x\in\{-1,0,1\}$ are given by

- $A=B=0$, $C=\pm1$
- $A=\pm2$, $B=0$, $C=\mp1$
- $A=1$, $B=\pm1$, $C=-1$
- $A=-1$, $B=\pm1$, $C=1$

For $\alpha=1$, $(1)$ must turn into one of these in terms of $\beta$. As at least one of $u,v$ is non-zero, at least one of the factors in $(1)$ is non-constant and hence the first of the four options, degree 0, is excluded. It follows that the polynomial is of degree $2$, i.e., both $u$ and $v$ are non-zero. In fact, we find that $uv\in\{1,2\}$, which leaves us only with the possibilities $-2\beta^2+1$, $-\beta^2+\beta+1$, $-\beta^2+\beta+1$. At any rate,
$$(x_0+u)(y_0+v)=1.$$
The same argument for $\alpha=-1$ leads to
$$(x_0-u)(y_0-v)=1.$$
By subtracting, we find $(x_0,y_0)\perp(v,u)$.

Swapping the roles of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we find
$$(x_0+v)(y_0-u)=-1\quad\text{and}\quad (x_0-v)(y_0+u)=-1.$$
This time, by subtracting, we find $(x_0,y_0)\perp(-u,v)$. As $(v,u)\perp (-u,v)$, one of the three vectors must be zero, and the only candidate is $(x_0,y_0)$, as desired.

With that,
$ uv=1$ and $u^2-v^2=(u+v)(u-v)=1$, hence $u^2$ is a root of $x^2-x-1$, etc. etc.

Comment: It is toooo complicated. Please make it little bit simple.@Hagen von Eitzen

Comment: @anonymous "one of the three vectors must be zero, and the only candidate is $(x_0,y_0)$". This says that $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0).$ Recalling that $(x_0,y_0)$ is the center of the square, where the diagonals meet, this is exactly the result you asked for.